# Abbreviating h1 text in CSS Media Query

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a `<h1>` element that has the text "WHERE LIONS ROAM" (the name of my site which you can see here: http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk). How would I shorten the text to just **"WLR"** for mobile sized devices. I have a pre-existing media query like so (I have tried playing around with it but I can't seem to get it quite right):

```
    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    #wlr {
    display:none;
}
    #wlr:after {
    content: 'WLR';
}
    } /* end of media query block */
    </style>
```

Comment: if h1 is on display:none; so will be h1:after

Comment: Yes I'm aware my attempt is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a try with :before and width

```
h1 {width:0;height:1em;overflow:hidden;padding-right:2.5em}
h1:before {content:'WLR';padding:0 2px;}
```